# Looping only certain files on VLC

Tags: python, ubuntu, video, keypress, vlc

I'm using Ubuntu with VLC. VLC is playing a file in fullscreen, and is looping. Now, when I press a key, for example "k", I want VLC to start playing another file - but only once; when this file ends, VLC should start looping the first file again.

How can I accomplish this? Using VLC & Python bindings? I would be very grateful for a example.